# Titanium: ListView load remote images

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I've got the below bit of code which pull back a list of the users facebook contacts along with their profile picture, however the images are not loading for each user, it is only showing the images for a few users.

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/friends', {
        fields : 'first_name,last_name,id,installed,picture.width(120).height(120),gender'
    }, 'GET', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var d = JSON.parse(e.result);
            var pData = [];
            var iData = [];
            var row = d.data;
            row = row.sort(sortByName)
            for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {
                var img = row[i].picture.data.url
                if (row[i].installed) {
                    pData.push({
                        properties : {
                            title : row[i].first_name + " " + row[i].last_name,
                            id : row[i].id,
                            image : img,
                            gender : row[i].gender,
                            accessoryType : Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_DISCLOSURE
                        },
                        template : Ti.UI.LIST_ITEM_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT
                    });
                } else {
                    iData.push({
                        properties : {
                            title : row[i].first_name + " " + row[i].last_name,
                            id : row[i].id,
                            image : img,
                            accessoryType : Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_DISCLOSURE
                        },
                        template : Ti.UI.LIST_ITEM_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT
                    });

                }
            }
            var play = Ti.UI.createListSection({
                headerTitle : 'Play with Facebook Friends',
                items : pData
            });

            var invite = Ti.UI.createListSection({
                headerTitle : 'Invite Facebook Friends',
                items : iData
            });
            var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
                sections : [play, invite],
            });
            self.add(listView)
        } else {
            alert("Facebook Error");
        }
    })
```

The images are stored in `var img = row[i].picture.data.url` and pushed into the data array as part of `image : img` but not all images are loading.

Is there a way to force the images to load? and show a default image whilst they are loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to complete example to do exactly what you are trying to accomplish abaove

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/34758524584/alloy-listview-facebook-friends#.UgexZGRATrg

Comment: Perfect, that seems appears to have worked. looks like to add images in the ListView you need to define then with a template

Comment: glad it helped you out, the transition to alloy is not trivial, but the benefits make it worth the efforts